# my classes cant reach the first variable

Tags: c#

hello i was wondering what i am doing wrong? I am trying to set defaults and my student class and Columbia student class wont reach the first variable for some reason.

```
public class ColumbiaStudent : Student
{
        public bool isInOOP;

        public ColumbiaStudent()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            isInOOP = true;

        }

        public String About()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void GetOOPString()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
public class Student : Person
{
        public int NumCourses;
        public string SchoolName;

        public Student()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            Age = 17;
            Name = "Jeff";
            NumCourses = 1;
            SchoolName = "Columbia";


        }

        public string About()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void AddCourse()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DropCourse()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
public class Person
{
        public int Age;
        public string Name;

        public Person()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();


        }

        public string About()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a C# class, and not Java.

Comment: What do you expect the first line in the Student constructor to do?

Comment: i am just trying to set a default, i want to make a normal student that are those set parameters

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit please? Which variable you can't reach and under what conditions?

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Put any code that you want to execute *before* `throw new System.NotImplementedException();`. When you throw an Exception, any code after that `throw` is ignored.

Comment: I think he is either trolling, or has no idea of the code he has just posted.

Comment: ooh ok, well instead i just deleted the throws because they arent needed apparently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of those

```
throw new System.NotImplementedException();
```

They were probably added automatically. You should remove them. They throw errors to remind you that the code is not implemented yet.

Comment: ok i did that which worked, but now i have a namespace error which must mean there is something wrong with the curly braces?

Comment: If what you showed us is the whole file... then you are missing something.

Everything should be inside the curly braces of the namespace

`namespace whatever {
        // place classes here
}`

Replace whatever with whatever you want. Usually it looks like your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using

```
throw new System.NotImplementedException();
```

to alert the programmer using these classes that the method they are trying to use is not implemented in this class. This is ok to use in the person class and in the other classes where you have not implemented any functionality but in the constructor for the Student class and in the ColumbiaStudent class constructor this doesn't make any sense. You ARE implementing these functions and so you don't want to be throwing an System.NotImplementedException here. At the very least, the variables are not being set up because once you get to the line that throws the exception the method does not execute the rest of the code in that method i.e. the variable set up lines of code.